# Understanding scope in JS

Tags: javascript, scope

I was trying to understand variable scope in JavaScript and i cam across this weird problem that happens with browsers.I tried executing the below snippet in Firefox scratchPad

```
(function() {
console.log(myvar); // undefined
myvar = "local value";
})();
console.log(myvar);
```

and it printed:

```
local value 
local value
```

But when i tried including the same in  tag in a html page browser throws javascript error saying

> myvar is undefined.

What is happening?

Comment: The question is really not very relevant, as you're not using the `var` keyword anywhere, which means you're always in the global scope, so scope is not relevant at all in that code, other than the variable being global and accessible anywhere. If logging the variable before declaring works somewhere, it does something strange

Comment: Sounds like you are on a buggy version of scratchpad, testing it out in the the version that follows FF 29.0.1, I correctly get "myvar is not defined" as expected. As @adeneo said there is no scoping concerns here as myvar is on the global scope.

Comment: @adeneo ok thanks. i was reading this tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals and was trying to execute the example. which worked at few places.. so wanted to understand why